# while uploading 6gb file ,im getting error in nginx server with python

Tags: gunicorn

nginx file
   client_max_body_size 30G;

settings.py

MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 1024*1024*1024*30
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o775

Comment: What is the error message you see?

Comment: Maybe POST size is also required (afaik from PHP).